# How to wait for the next v-blank without swapping buffers?

Tags: opengl, x11, egl, wayland

In an OpenGL application using EGL on X11 or Wayland, is there a way to wait for the next v-blank without swapping buffers?

I'm writing an OpenGL app and I only want to redraw when the content actually changes and I still want to have a way to run animations at the screen refresh rate even if I'm not drawing anything.

Comment: [This Swap Interval wiki link](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Swap_Interval) has useful hints.

Comment: On x11 you redraw on expose events. Make the animation send expose events to the windows affected by it.

Comment: @Andreas the question is how do I know when to invoke that animation